# getElementById in a FOR loop not working

Tags: php, javascript, dhtml

I'm not sure why this isn't working.

I have a record list of text fields in a form:

```
<input type="text" id="x1_Order">
<input type="text" id="x2_Order">
<input type="text" id="x3_Order">
<input type="text" id="x4_Order">
<input type="text" id="x5_Order">
...
<input type="text" id="x253_Order">
<input type="text" id="x254_Order">
<input type="text" id="x255_Order">
```

$NumberOfTotalRecords = 255

And using this PHP/Javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="for(i=0;i<=<?= $NumberOfTotalRecords ?>;i++){document.getElementById('x' . i . '_Order').value=i;}">Function</a>
```

When I click the *Function* link to trigger the javascript, in Google Chrome Developer Javascript Console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Comment: Try placing the onclick function into it's own actual function, and call that function from the onclick.  It should give you a better error, including a line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="for(i=0;i<=<?= $NumberOfTotalRecords ?>;i++){document.getElementById('x' . i . '_Order').value=i;}">Function</a>
```

The `.` operator is string concatenation in php.  Try using the `+` operator for string concatenation in javascript.

```
document.getElementById('x' + i + '_Order')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Plus I needed to change the starting number for(i=0; to for(i=1; since the first id is x1_Order, not x0_Order

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it as follws

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function abc() {
      for(i=1;i<=<?= $NumberOfTotalRecords ?>;i++){
        document.getElementById('x'+i+'_Order').value=i;
      }
    }
</script>

   <a href="#" onclick="abc()">Function</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The concat operator in javascript is +, not .